# Looking for a short story about a man who is visiting a planet where you get your position/job through playing a game

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story 8-15 years ago in German.
I'm not sure but I think the book had 2 short, totally different stories in it.

The story was about a man who was sent (I think kinda forced to go) to a planet where he should play a game everyone on that planet plays. I think the goal was to beat their leader and conquer the world like this?

The better you are at the game, the higher is your position in the society.
I remember that at the end he was playing against the leader and they had a long back and forth game, but I'm not sure who won.

They played the game on a different planet that had only one stripe of forest around the whole planet and a fire that goes around it.
But thats only the location they were playing.

The man was chosen because he was the best player in every game if I remember correctly.

The game was a board like game where you have troops or armies that you move around. It was not an easy game everyone just could play.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That is certainly [*The Player of Games*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Player_of_Games) by Iain M Banks, the second of his Culture books, which has all the elements you describe.

To quote Wikipedia:

> Gurgeh lands on the Empire's home planet of Eä, accompanied by another
>   drone, Flere-Imsaho. As a Culture citizen, he naturally plays with a
>   style markedly different from his opponents, many of whom stack the
>   odds against him one way or another, such as forming backroom
>   agreements to cooperate against him (which is allowed by the game's
>   rules). As he advances through the tournament he is matched against
>   increasingly powerful Azad politicians, and ultimately the Emperor
>   himself in the final round. The final contests take place on
>   Echronedal, the Fire Planet, which undergoes a natural conflagration
>   fueled by native plants that produce huge amounts of oxygen. The final
>   game is timed to end when the flames engulf the castle where the event
>   takes place, symbolically renewing the Empire by fire. However, faced
>   with defeat, the Emperor orders his men to kill all the spectators,
>   and then attempts to kill Gurgeh, but he is himself killed by a shot
>   from his own weapon, deflected by Flere-Imsaho (who later refuses to
>   tell Gurgeh if it was coincidental).

It's a novel not a short story, but it's a relatively short novel by modern standards and could have been in an omnibus volume with some other work.

Comment: One of a select list of books for which  own multiple copies :)

Comment: Awesome book - together with almost all other books of Ian M. Banks. I don't personally care so much for the books of Ian Banks (with M. = SciFi, without M = thriller/horror(ish), but it's the same guy), but can wholeheartedly recommend to check other books of the "M." guy. :)

Comment: @AnoE -- you should reconsider some of the Iain Banks books.  I don't know how your tastes run, exactly, but at least *Song of Stone* and *The Business* are SF-ish (but not "space opera") and worth reading.

Answer (score -3):

For completeness I'll put this in.

Given the short story comment - or rather the appearance of 2 stories in one - there's an outside chance this is one of the Apprentice Adept books by Piers Anthony.  Synopsis - its 2 worlds portal fantasy -  A fantasy world and a SciFi world.
The in the SciFi world you are ranked according to how well you play a set of game to escape Indentured Serfdom....

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept

My money is on Player of Games tho...